# How can I slow down my media time stamp in Camtasia 2023 so it is in sync with a slowed down video?

Tags: video, editing

I have a Camtasia video where the main track is playing at half-speed (slo-mo). I want to have a media timestamp or clock of some kind that shows the correct amount of elapsed time. My main track is at half-speed and a plain media timestamp shows twice the actual elapsed time. How can I show the accurate elapsed time? I'm using Camtasia 2023 (Windows).

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do it the hard way. The solution is simply to:

1. create the video and timer running at normal speed
2. export it as an MP4
3. create a new Camtasia project and add the MP4 to the timeline
4. slow down the video (with the timer) to half-speed and export to mp4

The key is to produce the video with the timer and it's natively synced. Then that composite (video with timer) can be slowed down and both timer and video are slowed down together.